# Comparing two Strings s = "ja".concat("va"); and s1=s.intern(); with == operator returns false. Why?

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

1. For Eg: When I compare two strings with == operator after I call intern() method it returns true.

   ```
   String name = "Wahab"; // in string literal pool
   String fullName = new String("Wahab"); // new string in heap
   String f = fullName.intern(); // pushing into string literal pool
   System.out.print(name == f); // **true**
   ```
2. Using Concat and invoke intern(), == operator returns true.

   ```
   String name = "Wahab".concat("Shaikh"); // concat with new string
   String fullName = name.intern(); // invoke intern to push into string literal pool
   System.out.print(name == fullName); // **true**
   ```
3. Having fewer chars, concatenate and invoke intern() then it returns false.

   ```
   String a = "ja".concat("va"); // concat with fewer characters
   String a1 = a.intern(); // push into literal pool and assign to new variable

   System.out.print(a == a1); // **false**
   ```

   Why is the third output false? 
   Please help.

Comment: JVM to run your code needs to load many other classes (like `java.lang.String` for instance) and at some point `"java"` string must have been put in string pool before you tried to `.intern()` it and you got back that string created earlier (you are not replacing string in pool with new one) which is confirmed by `==` result.

Comment: I gave it a try and it gave **true** for third one too. But if I create a variable which has value **java** then it gave false.

Comment: Why is this important?  Regardless of whether it "works", comparing strings with `==` is just plain wrong.  You cannot know in advance 100% of what is already in the string pool, as you found out, and the result can depend on many things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`String.intern()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern()) doc:

> When the intern method is invoked:
>   - if the pool already contains a string equal to this String object as determined by the equals(Object) method, then **the string from the pool is returned**.
>   - Otherwise, this String object is added to the pool and **a reference to this String object is returned**.

So `"ja".concat("va").intern()` returns the instance of String "java" that already exists in the pool (because that string already exists in a lot of places in the JVM and is apparently interned). In your code, `a1` points to the pre-existing interned instance, and `a` points to the instance you just built.

And `"Wahab".concat("Shaikh").intern()` returns the instance of String "WahabShaikh" that you just created.